# Make kafka consumer run forever

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka

I wrote a [high level Kafka consumer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example) as a part of a java application.

So the core code looks like this:

```
public void start() {
    ConsumerConnector consumerConnector = conf.getConsumerConnector();
    String topic = conf.getTopic();
    int numOfThereads = conf.getNumOfThreads();

    Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = ImmutableMap.of(topic, numOfThereads);
    Map<String, List<KafkaStream<Message>>> topicMessageStreams = consumerConnector.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
    List<KafkaStream<Message>> streams = topicMessageStreams.get(topic);

    // create 4 threads to consume from each of the partitions
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfThereads);

    // consume the messages in the threads
    for (final KafkaStream<Message> stream : streams) {
        executor.submit(new ConsumerThread(stream));
    }
}
```

To test my consumer I also created a producer, wrote to kafka and then launched my consumer, it works.
Since the threads are executed inside a loop I'm not sure I get things right.
I would like my consumer to run forever and keep on consuming messages from kafka.

What is the right way to make it run forever?

Comment: How you are iterating the  message from Kakfa? As per their doc the they said `The interesting part here is the while (it.hasNext()) section. Basically this code reads from Kafka until you stop it.`

Comment: As far as my tests go it seems you are right and the consumer keeps on working in the bg unless I stop it. feel free to post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@forhas Thanks for confirming

Basically from the documentation the way they iterate over the consumed message is given as below

```
    ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = m_stream.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
        System.out.println("Thread " + m_threadNumber + ": " + new String(it.next().message()));
```

And it also state that 
`The interesting part here is the while (it.hasNext()) section. Basically this code reads from Kafka until you stop it`  ..

So ideally it should be keep on running unless and until we kill it explicitly and once a new message has been produced the same would be available on the consumer side.